# How to make a custom total order relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

let $A:=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

Define a total order relation in A where 3 is the minimum

**I'd like to make a total order relation where the order is $3<1<2<4<5<6$.
How could I make it?**

I guess it's a real numbers usual order modification. I think my relation should take these ordered pairs
$$
R = \{ 
(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6), \\ 
(1,1),(1,2),(1,4),(1,5), 1,6), \\
(2,2),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6), \\ 
(4,4),(4,5),(4,6),\\
(5,5),(5,6),\\
(6,6) \\
\}
$$

Obviously it is a $A\times A$ subset so

$$R = \{(a,b) \in A \times A : \text{I don't know what should I write here}\}$$

I can't figure out how to do it

Maybe it could be $(x=3 \rightarrow \text{something})$ otherwise usual order

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Why include $6$?

Comment: Why are there pairs with $6$ if $6$ is not in $A$?

Comment: What do you mean by "make it"?  What more is there to do than to simply define the relevant inequalities?

Comment: So sorry it was my mistake, I think now it's ok

Comment: @lulu what do you mean? like define relation by enumerating its members?

Comment: I don't understand.  If you were to write, say, $3<1<2<4<5<6$, you are done, right?  That completely defines the order and it is clear that $3$ is minimal.  What else is there to be said?

Comment: Now that you added $6$ to $A$, $3<1<2<4<5$ doesn't specify how $6$ is related with the other numbers.

Comment: @lulu I'd like to write my relation as $R := \{ (a,b) \in A : \text{logic stuff}\}$

Comment: sorry @jjagmath my mistake again, it's ok now (I think)

Comment: I don't know what "logic stuff" might mean.  If you want, define a map $f:A\to A$ by $f(1)=2,f(2)=3, f(3)=1,f(4)=4,f(5)=5,f(6)=6$ and define a new order, $<'$ on $A$ by $a<'b \iff f(a)<f(b)$.  Is that the sort of thing you had in mind?

Comment: that's helpful but I can't use functions, it's supposed to be next topic so I can't use them :c (but thanks :D)

Answer (score 1):

If you insist in writing the relation in comprehension notation, you could write $R=\{(a,b)\in A\times A : a = 3 \text{ and } b \in A \text{ or } a = 1 \text{ and } b \in \{1,2,4,5,6\} \text{ or } a=2 \text{ and } b \in \{2,4,5,6\}  \text{ or } a=4 \text{ and } b \in \{4,5,6\} \text{ or } a=5 \text{ and } b \in \{5,6\} \text{ or } a=b=6\}$